Wireguard not showing in advanced network - auto connect
I have wireguard up and running great, but I want it to automatically connect when on certain WiFi networks. This is option in the advanced network window but the VPN is not showing up. I previously had this working on a different device on Ubuntu 20
VPN setup and functional:

Does not show as an automatic connect option:

